# how to make the phone call background through my app in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9

I am developing an app.
One of my app features is making calls.
Is there any api's available for making calls.

I am using the following code when this code is executed Apple's default call screen appears and my app goes to the background.
I want to launch a call in the background and keep my app running in foreground.

```
 NSURL* callUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",dailernum]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:callUrl];
```

Comment: this is not possible as @rckoenes indicated, but you can make a local notification when the phone call starts that the user can click to go back to the app and keep the call in the bakground

Comment: How Can I  Make That Notification. Give me any Link .............                 Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, Apple has restricted this with good reason. 
If it would be possible to start a phone call and which is not visible fro the user your app could be dialing a payed number. 
This would mean that the user is not aware of this and gets surprise when the phone bill drops in.

Also be aware that the `telprompt:` scheme is not official. Thus Apple might remove this at any time make your app not longer work.

To answer your other question, you can not make calls without either the `tel:` or `telprompt:`.

Comment: HI so .. i have one more ......... idea...                                                            How to add the Apples Default Calling  to my subview for my view controller .Is This Possible  to add subview(i think in android it working  ).  thank you

Comment: No also not possible, the dialer is not available for developers. You only option, as a stated earlier, is to user `tel:` or `telprompt:`.